# Laravel 5.2 HTTP error 500

Tags: php, laravel, server, laravel-5

I have made a website with Laravel 5.2 and now want to put it in my VPS. I installed LAMP on my server, and put my project in /www/ directory. I can access my server, however, when I try to access `/public`, I get an HTTP 500 error. Both my `/bootstrap/cache` and `/storage` are writable. Do you have any suggestions, what should I do? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just made a mistake on changing rights of bootstrap and storage folders... Very sorry... Everything works now!